# 7-zip command lines to add password-protection to unprotected zip file

Tags: passwords, zip, password-protection, 7zip

Suppose I already have an existing zip file `Unprotected.zip`. I want to add password protection to `Unprotected.zip`. I want to use 7-zip command-line version to accomplish this task. How should the 7-zip command lines look like to achieve this goal?

Comment: related (doesnt talk about command line though): https://superuser.com/questions/214823/add-password-to-existing-zip-file-with-7zip

Answer (score 6):

I think there is no one-step solution to do this.
We have to extract the zip file, and then pack it to zip file.
For example:

```
7z e Unprotected.zip

7z a Protected.zip -pPASSWORD UNPROTECTEDFILENAME
```

Replace the capital letters into your own string.

Refer to 
[Add](http://helpdoc-online.com/SCS0001EN1A3P22~7-Zip-9.21-Help-en~a-Add.htm) 
[Set-Password](http://helpdoc-online.com/SCS0001EN1A3P39~7-Zip-9.21-Help-en~-p-Set-Password.htm)